# How to read Unicode file in R

Tags: r, unicode, utf-8

I have one unicode (UTF-8) file with column delimiter as 'þ', I'm trying to read it using R csv reader as follows

```
data <- read.csv(file_name,,sep="þ",encoding="UTF-8")
```

in my data frame I'm getting everything in a single column, can someone correct me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I think your script needs to be encoded as utf-8 too if you're using non-ascii characters.

Save your code in for example `myfile.r` and then

Try this:

```
source("myfile.r", encoding="utf-8")
```

hopefully your error will go away